# Image uploaded from gallery not visible on Motorola device

Tags: android, image, bitmap, upload, gallery

I need to upload an image from the Gallery of my mobile and show it. I use this code.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
        postImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

When I use it in a Samsung device it works, whether when I try it on a Motorola, it doesn't work. The problem is that the bitmap seems to be empty.
I tried to upload images from the SD card and from the main storage, but the bitmap is always empty.
Somebody knows how to solve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: You might try to show the image path via toast, log or a textview in your layout, so you can check if it's a valid path.

Comment: The path is
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150218_093658121.jpg... Should be correct!

Comment: I don't know... you might consider using Picasso library to load images and check if it works in Motorola devices. Sorry